# Show that there exists a subsequence $\{E_{n_k}\}$ of $\{E_n\}$ such that $m(\cap_{k=1}^\infty E_{n_k})>\epsilon$ under these conditions....

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Question**: Let $\{E_n\}$ be a sequence of nonempty Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}m(E_n)=1$.  Show that for each $0<\epsilon<1$ there exists a subsequence $\{E_{n_k}\}$ of $\{E_n\}$ such that $m(\cap_{k=1}^\infty E_{n_k})>\epsilon$.

**My Thoughts**: I am a bit stumped on this one.  I am sure there is a technical way of doing it, but in my head, and this could be completely wrong, was thinking about taking each $E_n$ and, say, cut it in half and take the half such that the distance between any point on the interval of the cut and $0.5$ is smallest.  If the half cut overlaps $0.5$, then choose that one. If the middle of the subset is exactly on $0.5$, then make the cut, and shift the subset to the left (or right) the length of $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.  Then, we get a bunch of subsequences that all lay "on top" of $0.5$, so they don't have an empty intersection, and that would solve our problem (I think).  But, I am a bit worried about the "for each $0<\epsilon<1$, because, say, if $\epsilon=0.8$, then my method wouldn't necessarily work, but really only works for a "small enough" $\epsilon$.  Maybe a more technical approach would be best...

Any thoughts, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $m(E_n^{c}) \to 0$. Choose an increasing sequence of integers $n_k$ such that $m(E_{n_k}^{c}) <\frac  {1-\epsilon} {2^{k}}$. Then $m(\cup_k E_{n_k}^{c}) \leq \sum_k m(E_{n_k}^{c}) <1-\epsilon$ and $m(\cap_k E_{n_k})=1-m(\cup_k E_{n_k}^{c}) >\epsilon$